# MPLABX on Linux & spaces in the Microchip library file names

Tags: linux, compiler-construction, pic, microchip, mplab

I think this is a problem with bringing a set of "helper" or "library" files from the Windows world to the Unix / Linux world.  Has anyone else had the problem where an MPLABX project can compile on a Windows machine and fail to do so on a Linux machine.  It is starting to look like the spaces in file names deep inside the C code authored and distributed by Microchip are not handled correctly on the Linux machine.  That is, some tools are probably "ok" with the space in the file names Microchip chose to use and others are saying they can not find the files.

Both Windows and Linux are being run on the same "duel boot" machine.  The project files are freshly checked out from the same SVN repository.  And I believe both copies of MPLABX are up to date.  It would be hard to imagine any other way to eliminate other differences.  Which leaves the way MPLABX is handling files to be one of the few remaining differences.

-thanks

Comment: I've seen issues where people accidentally check .o or .o.d files into source-control and other strange issues like this. Have you tried to make a completely fresh project on the Linux side and only copy over .c and .h. Not sure if this would help, but I have solved MPLABX issues this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that Microchip knows about these issues and I was led to believe they are cleaning up the Microchip libraries this fall (fall of 2013).  I assume in a effort to remove the spaces.

Thanks to everyone who took interest in and read my question.